# Merge two dataframe and create new on with smaller values

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, merge, min

I am trying to merge two dataframes (same size) and create new dataframe that contains the smaller number of two values in same column and row.
For example, two dataframes are:

df1

```
1 2 3
2 2 5
5 3 2
```

df 2

```
2 1 2
4 4 2
3 2 4
```

The desired output would be

```
1 1 2
2 2 2
3 2 2
```

In other words, compare each value in two dataframes and picks the smaller number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmin` to get the `min` of each corresponding elements

```
pmin(df1, df2)
#   v1 v2 v3
#1  1  1  2
#2  2  2  2
#3  3  2  2
```

Or if there are multiple datasets, place it in a `list` and apply `pmin`

```
do.call(pmin, list(df1, df2))
#   v1 v2 v3
#1  1  1  2
#2  2  2  2
#3  3  2  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 2L, 5L), v2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L), v3 = c(3L, 
 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c(2L, 4L, 3L), v2 = c(1L, 4L, 2L), v3 = c(2L, 
 2L, 4L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```